# Selecting a specific letters from a character after a specific symbol

Tags: r, regex

Need to take out all the characters before "(" and combine them with ";"

```
stringr::word(pilist, 2, sep = '(\\s*|\\')

pilist = "pi1(tag1,tag2);pi2(tag3,tag4,tag5);"
```

I expect the output as

```
"pi1;pi2"
```

Comment: Quick and dirty solution - `paste(sub("\\(.*", "", strsplit("pi1(tag1,tag2);pi2(tag3,tag4,tag5);", ";")[[1]]), collapse = ";")`. But it's far from perfect and regex should solve this easily

Comment: Try `gsub("\\([^()]*\\)", "", pilist)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this pattern

```
\([^)]+\)|;+$
```

[image]

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/zJWvZO/3/)

Note:- Use escape character as `\\` or `\` depending on your regex engine

Answer (score 1):

If you are string has the exact same structure as shown, we can remove everything which comes between round brackets and the trailing `;` using `gsub`

```
gsub("\\(.*?\\)|;$", "", pilist)
#[1] "pi1;pi2"
```

---

However, following your description it can also be done by extracting the words which we want instead of removing. Using `str_extract_all`

```
paste0(stringr::str_extract_all(pilist, "(\\w+)(?=\\(.*\\))")[[1]], collapse = ";")
#[1] "pi1;pi2"
```

Comment: You wrap them in `trimws(..., whitespace = ';')` to get rid of trailing `;`

Comment: @Sotos yeahh..or maybe wrap another `sub` to remove `;$`.

Comment: or even something like `paste(strsplit('pi1;p12;', ';')[[1]], collapse = ';')` :D